# How surgeries are performed on military and hospital ships?

Tags: surgery

I am intersted in papers or reports on how the operations are conducted in the presence of permanent pitching.

Is it even possible to perform, for example, heart transplant in such conditions?

What operations are known to be possible to perform?

How military ships are expected to surgically treat wounded crew in case of a storm?

Are there any special pieces of equipment that increase the probability of success for a range operations?

Please note that I do not have any medical background.

P.S. I would really appreciate links and references

## Previous research

[Here](https://www.mercyships.org/first-surgery-on-board-global-mercy/) I found that it is indeed possible to perform somewhat complex surgeries while afloat.

Then I found [the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1931720418306822?via%3Dihub) which reviews some aspects of surgery on military ships. But it lacks details and focuses on differences between training and real practice instead of methods used by "Ship's Surgeons".

There is [another](https://doi.org/10.5055/ajdm.2012.0101) report that I liked, but again it lacks details. Ideally, I want to know the difference between operating on a ship and on a shore.

This [paywalled research](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29889958/) states that there is no significant difference while operation afloat. I was not able to steal the article, so I don't know the methodology and can't judge if it is valid research.

Comment: What hits did you get when you googled "what kinds of surgeries are performed on hospital ships" / ["... military sick bays"]  or a similar query? Note that such ships are in a harbor; no permanent pitching involved.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I updated post with the most interesting results I got by myself

Comment: That "Surgery at Sea" article was pretty cool and the abstract you linked was sufficient. It described the methodology sufficiently to conclude it was probably a reasonably well run study. You did some nice prior research, better than most we get here. Thank you and +1.

Comment: Remember that you can answer your own question.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I will provide an answer after the hope of getting one from somebody else dies out. I hope that maybe somebody with actual medical expertise or, even better, with relevant experience will provide an answer containing details and know-how's that I can't possibly find out any other way

Comment: Okay, but keep in mind this is a small site and your question is very niche. I can't recall ever seeing anyone here with a medical and military background.